# How to browse a drive on a different network?

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share

We have 2 different network structures and need to browse and map a network share from other network. (I have a windows share that I can reach and map from my local network and want the same thing from our other network.)

How can I do that? Which port should I open on the firewall? (I can’t open NetBIOS for security reasons.)

Comment: Explain better both networks details and how they're connected

Comment: they connected via fortigate and If we need any source from any network we are creating a rule and accept it.

Comment: they connected via fortigate and If we need any source from any network we are creating a rule and accept it. but now I dont have any idea how do I do that? which port I need to add to the firewall?I can not do that with netbios .

Comment: Instead of opening up all those ports, why don't you create a VPN between the networks.   Is that possible in your situation?

Comment: no way ,I agree with you technically but the administration does not want it.I have to browse remote disks as locally.its a very complicated situation I know that.

Comment: I can't imagine how to browse remote disks locally :/

Answer (score 0):

Given the constraints that you have listed in the comments, I suggest using web sharing (WebDAV) for the remote share, since Windows supports it natively. Your firewall administer will probably be more amenable to opening HTTP traffic (port 80) instead of a standard file sharing protocol like CIFS/SMB. You will need to connect via IP or DNS name as browsing won't really work in the absence of a service location protocol like NetBIOS.